# Is there any better option to apply pagination without applying OFFSET in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, keyset-pagination

I want to apply pagination on a table with huge data. All I want to know a better option than using OFFSET in SQL Server.

Here is my simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Id DESC 
OFFSET 30000000 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Yes. https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Comment: Why do you need a *better option* than `OFFSET / FETCH` ? What's wrong with `OFFSET / FETCH` ??

Comment: Do you really need to jump to page 1,500,000? Perhaps you need a better criteria?

Comment: @marc_s Recently I have learnt that the way OFFSET works are by counting how many rows it should skip. After that it is giving your result. In other words, to get the results from rows 30000000 to 30000020 it needs to scan through the first 30000000 and then throw them away. It seems to much wasteful. So I want to know a better option to apply server side pagination if there exist any better way.

Comment: See also https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset, it's called Keyset Pagination.

Comment: @The Impaler Can you please explain about Sing key set pagination? Actually I want to know better approach if there exist any

Comment: @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot I'm sorry it was a typo. I meant "Keyset Pagination". The answer below describes it.

Comment: Is there a real world use for this? Does someone really need to look at 30 millionth row?

Comment: @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot You needed to actually manually award the bounty if it was placed after you accepted my answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107139/bounty-disappeared

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to paginate results in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109232/what-is-the-best-way-to-paginate-results-in-sql-server)

Comment: @SalmanA yes -- when your client is not a human but machine readable there are numerous use cases

Comment: @Md.TarikulIslamSoikot,can you your table schema and existing index ,along with datatype ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**You can use [*Keyset Pagination*](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) for this.** It's [*far* more efficient](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) than using Rowset Pagination (paging by row number).

In Rowset Pagination, **all previous rows** must be read, before being able to read the next page. Whereas in Keyset Pagination, the server can jump **immediately** to the correct place in the index, so no extra rows are read that do not need to be.

For this to perform well, you need to have a unique index on that key, which includes any other columns you need to query.

In this type of pagination, you cannot jump to a specific page number. You jump to a specific key and read from there. So you need to save the unique ID of page you are on and skip to the next. Alternatively, you could calculate or estimate a starting point for each page up-front.

**One big benefit**, apart from the obvious efficiency gain, is avoiding the "missing row" problem when paginating, caused by rows being removed from previously read pages. This does not happen when paginating by key, because the key does not change.

---

**Here is an example:**

Let us assume you have a table called `TableName` with an index on `Id`, and you want to start at the latest `Id` value and work backwards.

You begin with:

```sql
SELECT TOP (@numRows)
  *
FROM TableName
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

> Note the use of `ORDER BY` to ensure the order is correct
>
> In some RDBMSs you need `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`

The client will hold the last received `Id` value (the lowest in this case). On the next request, you jump to that key and carry on:

```sql
SELECT TOP (@numRows)
  *
FROM TableName
WHERE Id < @lastId
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

> Note the use of `<` not `<=`

In case you were wondering, in a typical B-Tree+ index, the row with the indicated ID is *not* read, it's the row *after* it that's read.

---

**The key chosen *must* be unique**, so if you are paging by a non-unique column then you must add a second column to both `ORDER BY` and `WHERE`. You would need an index on `OtherColumn, Id` for example, to support this type of query. Don't forget `INCLUDE` columns on the index.

SQL Server does not support *row/tuple comparators*, so you cannot do `(OtherColumn, Id) < (@lastOther, @lastId)` (this is however supported in PostgreSQL, MySQL, MariaDB and SQLite).

Instead you need the following:

```sql
SELECT TOP (@numRows)
  *
FROM TableName
WHERE (
    (OtherColumn = @lastOther AND Id < @lastId)
    OR OtherColumn < @lastOther
)
ORDER BY
  OtherColumn DESC,
  Id DESC;
```

This is more efficient than it looks, as SQL Server can convert this into a proper `<` over both values.

The presence of `NULL`s complicates things further. You may want to query those rows separately.

Comment: So you cannot jump directly to 30,000,000th row unless you have read all previous rows to calculate the `@lastId`. How is this useful?

Comment: That's true, you cannot, and I did mention this. But it's pretty rare that a user actually *wants* to do so from the start. As you said yourself in a comment *"Does someone really need to look at 30 millionth row?"* Normally they might say "I'm up to this point in the list, I want the next few rows" and paginating by key works better for this, because the missing rows problem doesn't affect it (if you remove rows from earlier pages and you page by row-number then you will miss rows). It works very well for infinite scrolling, and for batch operations

Comment: I've been trying to implement keyset pagination but all the examples assume you're using a type which you can use the 'less than' or 'greater than' operand. If you are sorting by a string (and then a unique ID, which in my case is a GUID), what are we supposed to do? We can't do `string > string` and `string.Compare()` cannot be translated by EF.

Comment: Are you sure it can't be translated? It works fine for me. Either `string.Compare(a, b) > 0` or `a.CompareTo(b) > 0`. Do not use a `StringComparison` value, instead define your column with the right collation

Comment: @AndyFurniss GUIDs as PKs are non-performant, not a solution but try to avoid those in the first place unless you have a good reason to choose them.

Comment: Besides requiring reading rows sequentially as @SalmanA mentioned earlier. There is another problem. Say i wanted to sort the table by `updated_at` column. `updated_at` field get updated sporadically, so sorting by this column does not ensure that primary key / unique key will be continuous even after we include a primary key in the sort order.

Comment: Like I said, you need an index on whatever column you are sorting (plus possibly a unique column) so in that case you would have an index on `(updated_at, PK)` and the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` would also use both of those columns. The results are then always continuous in the specified order, and if you go ascending you won't miss or duplicate any rows while paging.

Comment: what is the advantage of having updated_at as the first key? why cant i do (id, updated_at desc). It will sort by id and updated_at and store it by default in the order I want and then I use where clause to keyset paginate?

Comment: No, if `id` is the first column then you would need to paginate by `id` first. And given that `id` is unique, there is no need for any other columns. The point here is: you want to paginate by `updated-at`, but you need to uniquely identify a row so you add another column `id` which is unique. The pagination always goes in the same order as the key columns of the index.

Comment: @J.D. all you said has been established already.

Comment: @J.D. At the top of my post *"In Rowset Pagination, all previous rows must be read, before being able to read the next page. Whereas in Keyset Pagination, the server can jump immediately to the correct place in the index, so no extra rows are read that do not need to be."*

Comment: Yea @Charlieface, I know you explained that. But then they still asked what's the benefit after, so it seemed to go over their head. I was just summarizing with the industry terms, hoping it clarified.

Answer (score 8):

On very big merchant website we use a technic compound of ids stored in a pseudo temporary table and join with this table to the rows of the product table.

Let me talk with a clear example.

We have a table design this way :

```
CREATE TABLE S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN
(PGN_ID              BIGINT IDENTITY(-9 223 372 036 854 775 808, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
 PGN_SESSION_GUID    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
 PGN_SESSION_DATE    DATETIME2(0) NOT NULL,
 PGN_PRODUCT_ID      INT NOT NULL,
 PGN_SESSION_ORDER   INT NOT NULL);
CREATE INDEX X_PGN_SESSION_GUID_ORDER 
   ON S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN (PGN_SESSION_GUID, PGN_SESSION_ORDER)
   INCLUDE (PGN_SESSION_ORDER);
CREATE INDEX X_PGN_SESSION_DATE 
   ON S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN (PGN_SESSION_DATE);
```

We have a very big product table call T_PRODUIT_PRD and a customer filtered it with many predicates. We INSERT rows from the filtered SELECT into this table this way :

```
DECLARE @SESSION_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();
INSERT INTO S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN
SELECT @SESSION_ID , SYSUTCDATETIME(), PRD_ID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY --> custom order by
FROM   dbo.T_PRODUIT_PRD 
WHERE  ... --> custom filter
```

Then everytime we need a desired page, compound of @N products we add a join to this table as :

```
...
JOIN S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN
   ON PGN_SESSION_GUID = @SESSION_ID
      AND 1 + (PGN_SESSION_ORDER / @N) = @DESIRED_PAGE_NUMBER
      AND PGN_PRODUCT_ID = dbo.T_PRODUIT_PRD.PRD_ID
```

All the indexes will do the job !

Of course, regularly we have to purge this table and this is why we have a scheduled job which deletes the rows whose sessions were generated more than 4 hours ago :

```
DELETE FROM S_TEMP.T_PAGINATION_PGN
WHERE  PGN_SESSION_DATE < DATEADD(hour, -4, SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as SQLPro solution, I propose:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT 30000000  AS N
UNION ALL SELECT N-1 FROM CTE
WHERE N > 30000000 +1 - 20)
SELECT T.* FROM CTE JOIN TableName T ON CTE.N=T.ID
ORDER BY CTE.N DESC
```

Tried with 2 billion lines and it's instant !
Easy to make it a stored procedure...
Of course, valid if ids follow each other.

Comment: "Of course, valid if ids follow each other" - oh