# Dealing with paging when [partially] duplicate records exist

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, pagination

I have a code which calls a single page using SQL like this

```sql
select
  <some fields>,
  count(*) over.. as _$total_records
From
  <some inline view>
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET ...
FETCH ...
```

This SQL might return duplicated `ids` due to a join. And this was OK in the most of the cases. But a new requirement is to suppress duplicates. However, I must not suppress certain fields that are coming from the join which brings duplicates. In other words I need result set like this

From

| id | name | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 55 |
| 1 | A | 66 |
| 2 | B | 11 |
| 3 | C | 77 |
| 3 | C | 88 |

To

| id | name | reference |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 55 |
| 2 | B | 11 |
| 3 | C | 77 |

I was thinking about this logic (pseudo code)

```cs
while (resultModelList.Count < pageSize && recordsReturned)
{

    reader = CallDb(sql);
    LoadPage(reader, resultModelList, out recordsReturned);

}
```

In this case ^^ `LoadPage` will check if the `id` is already added into the list and skip adding this record. And operation will repeat until page size is satisfied or no more records returned by the `reader`.

But I see potential issues with skipped records. And also correct page number due to `count() over`. Is there a good way to deal with it?

**Update:** this question is not about SQL solution but about paging solution. SQL here is built dynamically. It can have 1,2,3 joins based on configuration and criteria values. All these items are added dynamically. The `SELECT` is built dynamically.

Comment: You need to decide which row you want to return. Presumably you need some kind of `ROW_NUMBER` solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group. If you use a deterministic ordering you won't have skipped rows because that, but `OFFSET FETCH` can still have issues with skipped rows for a different reason: inserts and deletes in between each query. This is one of the reasons why [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997) is much better

Comment: @Charlieface  in this case it is not important which row is returned. The `order by` will be done by one of the columns and always `id`. Which `reference` is returned - don't matter. Or, we can, in fact, set it to "multiple" during `reader` parsing. I will look into your solution

Comment: Are you wanting to page in SQL Server or in C#? Pick one and then clarify your question. As it exists much of your question refers to eliminating duplicate records. If thats not your question, then remove it.

Comment: **This question is not about SQL-only solution** as so-called duplicate is about. This question is about paging. And solution is not necessary SQL-only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done witn using a nested select with `Row_Number` and pick up the appropriate rows with `Partition By`, something like this:

```sql
select
  <some fields>,
  count(*) over.. as _$total_records
From
  (
  select
  <some fields>,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY reference) rw 
From
  <some inline view>
  ) tbl
WHERE tbl.rw=1
ORDER BY ...
OFFSET ...
FETCH ...
```

Comment: I got to give you for this. Although my problem is more complex, due to use of Oracle, MySql, not only Sql Server. And MySql does not have full support. However, sql server works. We employed in-code solution, which wasn't perfect, and now we're back to the drawing board