# Performance issue with "OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH Next 10 ROWS only"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have SQL where am using row offset to perform pagination, which is taking around 10minutes to return 32 records, but without using row offset my query giving 500+ records within second.

So I want to understand what could be have been lead to this issue. Could anyone help.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please check if there is an index on the affected column and if not, create it and try agin?

Comment: Please only tag the actual version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: There are actually loads of articles around about this being a performance issue, google "sql server best performing paging"

Comment: Pretty sure SQL Server 2008 didn't support `OFFSET`, so are you *sure* you're using SQL Server 2008? 2008 is also *completely* unsupported, for almost 3 years, so I strongly suggest you sort out that upgrade path ASAP.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457

Comment: To Answer your queries
@JonasMetzler we have all the required index, if remove "offset 0 fetch next 10 rows only" from my select statement it works just fine, only "row offset" feature is causing trouble.

Comment: @Larnu Am using the 2019 SQL server

Comment: Are you sure about your indexes? Did you have a look to the execution plan?

Comment: *"Am using the 2019 SQL server"* then why did you tag [[tag:sql-server-2008]] and why is [[tag:sql-server-2014]] still tagged..?

Answer (score 0):

My user database(App) and system database (temp db) were using different compatibility, as soon I set the compatibility same as system database, it worked like charm.