# c# SQLDataAdapter syntax error near @parameterName

Tags: c#, sql, sqldataadapter

I have to run a query in a SqlDataAdapter but I am having problems with syntax error near @parameterName.
My code:

```
con.Open();
        string sql ="select top @take * from"+
"(Select ProductName, CategoryName, CompanyName, UnitPrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductId) AS ROW_NUM "+
"from Products as p inner join Categories as c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID "+
"inner join Suppliers as s on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID "+
") as x "+
"where x.ROW_NUM > @skip ";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
            
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 20;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@skip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10;
          /* */ 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            repProducts.DataSource = dt;
            repProducts.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: If I am not horrendously mistaken, I do not think SQLParams work for take and skip.

Comment: I thought it would be possible, but i guess you are right

Comment: Well, you are hard-coding them anyway, so you can as well put them into the query as literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass a parameter, variable or calculation for `TOP` you need to put it into `()` paranethesis. This is called out in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#compatibility-support):

> For backward compatibility, the parentheses are optional in `SELECT` statements if the expression is an integer constant. We recommend that you always use parentheses for `TOP` in `SELECT` statements.

- You are also missing `using` in various places.
- You can use a verbatim string instead of concatenating, and embed newlines directly in the string.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

const string sql = @"
select top (@take)
  *
from (
    Select
      ProductName,
      CategoryName,
      CompanyName,
      UnitPrice,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ProductId) AS ROW_NUM
    from Products as p
    inner join Categories as c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
    inner join Suppliers as s on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
) as x
where x.ROW_NUM > @skip;
";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con))
{
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@take", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 20;
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@skip", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 10;
    con.Open();
    adapter.Fill(dt);
}
repProducts.DataSource = dt;
repProducts.DataBind();
```

You also don't need the `ROW_NUMBER`, as SQL Server now offers the `OFFSET FETCH` syntax:

```cs
const string sql = @"
select
  ProductName,
  CategoryName,
  CompanyName,
  UnitPrice
from Products as p
inner join Categories as c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
inner join Suppliers as s on p.SupplierID = s.SupplierID
ORDER BY ProductId
OFFSET @skip ROWS FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY;
";
```

You may also want to take a look at this post, among others, on the inefficiency of Rowset Pagination:
[Is there any better option to apply pagination without applying OFFSET in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457)