# ERROR in SQL order by with case when expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I prepare a SQL query and I use a `case-when expression` for ordering purposes. If I used `req_amount` or  `apply_date` as sort_column it works fine. But I use `emp_name` for sorting, I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Please help me to resolve this.

```
DECLARE @srch_text varchar(50) = 'Cha'
DECLARE @page_no int = 1
DECLARE @page_size int = 10
DECLARE @sort_column  varchar(50) = 'emp_name'
DECLARE @order varchar(50) = 'ASC'

if (@order  = 'asc' OR @order = 'ASC')
BEGIN
select i.TRN_ID,e.EMP_FULLNAME,i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT,i.BET_APPLY_DATE 
from INTERMEDIATE i
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON i.BET_EMP_NUMBER = e.EMP_NUMBER 
where e.EMP_FULLNAME LIKE '%'+@srch_text+'%'
ORDER BY 
CASE @sort_column
    WHEN 'req_amount' THEN i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT
    WHEN 'emp_name' THEN  e.EMP_FULLNAME
    WHEN 'apply_date' THEN i.BET_APPLY_DATE
    END   asc 
OFFSET @page_size * ((@page_no - 1)) ROWS FETCH NEXT @page_size ROWS ONLY
END
ELSE
BEGIN
select i.TRN_ID,e.EMP_FULLNAME,i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT,i.BET_APPLY_DATE 
from INTERMEDIATE i
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON i.BET_EMP_NUMBER = e.EMP_NUMBER 
where e.EMP_FULLNAME LIKE '%'+@srch_text+'%'
ORDER BY 
CASE @sort_column
    WHEN 'req_amount' THEN i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT
    WHEN 'emp_name' THEN  e.EMP_FULLNAME
    WHEN 'apply_date' THEN i.BET_APPLY_DATE
    END desc 
OFFSET @page_size * ((@page_no - 1)) ROWS FETCH NEXT @page_size ROWS ONLY
END
```

Comment: If you use CASE then you must use **explicit** convertion to **the same** (compatible) datatype for all WHEN/ELSE options.

Comment: probably simplest is to use three separate case whens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate `ORDER BY` expressions.

```sql
SELECT
  i.TRN_ID,
  e.EMP_FULLNAME,
  i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT,
  i.BET_APPLY_DATE 
FROM INTERMEDIATE i
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON i.BET_EMP_NUMBER = e.EMP_NUMBER 
WHERE e.EMP_FULLNAME LIKE '%' + @srch_text + '%'
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN @order = 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'req_amount'  THEN i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT END,
  CASE WHEN @order = 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'emp_name'    THEN e.EMP_FULLNAME END,
  CASE WHEN @order = 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'apply_date'  THEN i.BET_APPLY_DATE END,
  CASE WHEN @order <> 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'req_amount' THEN i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT END,
  CASE WHEN @order <> 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'emp_name'   THEN e.EMP_FULLNAME END,
  CASE WHEN @order <> 'ASC' AND @sort_column = 'apply_date' THEN i.BET_APPLY_DATE END
OFFSET @page_size * ((@page_no - 1)) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @page_size ROWS ONLY;
```

Hvaing said that, it's probably better to just use dynamic SQL, as this is basically a Kitchen Sink Query. This means that indexes will get used properly (although the wildcard search is always going to be a problem).

Note the use of `sp_executesql` to pass parameters in.

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = '
SELECT
  i.TRN_ID,
  e.EMP_FULLNAME,
  i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT,
  i.BET_APPLY_DATE 
FROM INTERMEDIATE i
INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON i.BET_EMP_NUMBER = e.EMP_NUMBER 
WHERE e.EMP_FULLNAME LIKE ''%'' + @srch_text + ''%''
ORDER BY
  ' +

  CASE @sort_column
  WHEN 'req_amount' THEN 'i.REQUESTING_AMOUNT'
  WHEN 'emp_name'   THEN 'e.EMP_FULLNAME'
  WHEN 'apply_date' THEN 'i.BET_APPLY_DATE'
  ELSE '1'
  END +

  IIF(@order = 'ASC', ' ASC', ' DESC ') + '
OFFSET @page_size * ((@page_no - 1)) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @page_size ROWS ONLY;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,
  N'@srch_text varchar(200),
    @page_size bigint,
    @page_no bigint',
  @srch_text = @srch_text
  @page_size = @page_size,
  @page_no = @page_no;
```

You might want to take a read of [Is there any better option to apply pagination without applying OFFSET in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457) which explains why `OFFSET FETCH` is slow in general, and what to do instead.