# Return duplicate values When use Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, dapper

I call a stored procedure with Dapper. The stored procedure returns a pageable list. I have 30 records in the database.

But every series of repeated values is returned:

```cs
IEnumerable<TEntity> entities;
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@page", page, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameters.Add("@pageSize", pageSize, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameters.Add("@search", search, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

try
{
    _connection.Open();
    entities = await _connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>($"{storedProcedure}", parameters);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    return null;
}
finally
{
    _connection.Dispose();
    _connection.Close();
}

return entities.ToList();
```

This is the stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetCategories]
    @search nvarchar(300) = '',
    @page int = 1,
    @pageSize int = 10
AS
BEGIN
    SET @page = (@page - 1) * @pageSize;
    DECLARE @Sql Nvarchar(800)
    SET @Sql=' select * from Dy.Category As C With(Nolock) where  IsDeleted=0 ';

    IF @search IS NOT NULL AND @search <> ''
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql=@Sql+' AND C.Title like N''%''' +@search +'''%'' ' ;
    END

    SET @Sql = @Sql +' Order By CreateTime Desc OFFSET '+CAST(@page AS NVARCHAR(100))+

' ROWS FETCH NEXT ' +CAST(@pageSize AS NVARCHAR(100))+' ROWS ONLY';

    EXEC sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

Comment: The problem is the dynamic SQL code, not Dapper. You gain *nothing* by constructing a dynamic SQL string in the database. You're as exposed to SQL injection attacks and conversion problems as if you'd built the string on the client. And `NOLOCK` won't fix any performance problems caused by the lack of indexing, it will make them worse

Comment: If you want to page over an entire table (I suspect IsDeleted=0 isn't very selective), select all ID/PK values first, partition them in batches or ranges, and retrieve one batch at a time, using eg `ID IN (....)` or `ID between ....`. This way, instead of forcing the server to scan the table every time, you retrieve only eg 50 rows by primary key

Comment: Slight detour....https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: An even better idea would be to *not* use soft deletes. That's a programmer hack, not a business requirements. Business processes reverse transactions, they never mark them as deleted. Soft deletes don't scale as you found out *and* turn maintenance into a nightmare. In SQL Server you can use temporal tables for data that is only valid in a specific period of time, and still be able to check old data without keeping historical data in the "live" table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the command type:

`CommandType.StoredProcedure`

```
entities = await _connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>($"{storedProcedure}", parameters,commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the real problem, it only covers up a different bug in the code. The code is way overcomplicated too - you don't need `DynamicParameters`, you could have passed the parameters with an anonymous object, just like any other Dapper query. `dbConnection.Query<ResultTokenInput>("GetEventCategories", new { keyword = q },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)`. No need to explicitly open the connection

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues here. Firstly your C# code:

- Your primary issue: you need to specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, otherwise the parameters are not passed through.
- Do *not* cache the connection object. Create when you need it, dispose with `using`.
- Dapper will open and closed your connection for you automatically.
- You don't need to `ToList` unless you are using Dapper unbuffered mode.

```cs
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("@page", page, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameters.Add("@pageSize", pageSize, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
parameters.Add("@search", search, DbType.String, ParameterDirection.Input);

using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionStringHere);
var entities = await _connection.QueryAsync<TEntity>(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return entities;
```

You could also just use an anonymous type, although it's harder to be precise about data types in that case.

```cs
var parameters = new {
    page,
    pageSize,
    search
};
```

Your SQL:

- Do not use `NOLOCK`, it has serious data integrity implications.
- Do ***not*** inject raw data into your query, it's **dangerous**. Instead pass through the parameters via `sp_executesql`.
- Dynamic SQL should go into a `nvarchar(max)` variable.

```sql
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetCategories]
    @search nvarchar(300)='',
    @page int=1,
    @pageSize int=10
AS

SET @page = (@page - 1) * @pageSize;

DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = '
select *
from Dy.Category As C
where IsDeleted = 0
';

IF ISNULL(@search, '') <> ''
    SET @Sql += 'AND C.Title LIKE N''%'' + @search + ''%''
';

SET @Sql += '
ORDER BY
  CreateTime DESC
OFFSET @page ROWS FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql,
  N'@search nvarchar(300),
    @page int,
    @pageSize int',
    @search = @search,
    @page = @page,
    @pageSize = @pageSize;
```

Consider using [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997) rather than Rowset Pagination, as it's much more efficient.