# query window function aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a query like this to paginate and also get the row count. Can I modify this query to get all possible col3 from total results instead of current page?

```
select col1, col2, col3, count(1) over() as row_count 
from table1
where col2 in ('a','b')
order by col1
offset 0 rows fetch next 5 rows only
```

I want to avoid executing another query to get all the possible col3 values across pages. Obviously the data comes from multiple tables using joins.

```
Name    Course    Country    Row_Count    All_Countries
Jack    CS        USA        20           USA, UK, UAE, India, Canada
John    EE        UK         20           USA, UK, UAE, India, Canada
Will    IT        Canada     20           USA, UK, UAE, India, Canada
Kathy   Law       USA        20           USA, UK, UAE, India, Canada
Kelly   Med       UK         20           USA, UK, UAE, India, Canada
```

The idea is that per page has 5 rows.
First page only contains countries USA, UK and Canada.
But for the criteria, there are totally 20 rows and the countries are USA, UK, UAE, India and Canada.

Comment: This question was already asked by you yesterday

Comment: i deleted that question

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the window function in a subquery, before filtering using `OFFSET`.

```sql
select col1, col2, col3, row_count
from (
    select *,
      count(*) over() as row_count 
    from table1 t1
    where col2 in ('a','b')
) t1
order by col1
offset 0 rows fetch next 5 rows only;
```

Do note however, that rowset pagination is slow, and is compounded here by needing to retrieve all rows in order to calculate the rowcount. You are **far** better off using [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997), although this does not allow you to calculate a total rowcount.