# SQL Server paging query selecting spatial geometry data with where clause very slow compared to without

Tags: sql-server, performance, geometry, query-optimization, spatial

I've run into an odd combination of requirements that kills the performance of a query.  This is a table created by ESRI's ArcGIS server in SQL Server and the query comes from a feature service paging through data in the table.

This is slow [(paste the plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1g9DUOP6):

```
SELECT
    OBJECTID,
    Shape
FROM 
    dbo.PARCELS   
WHERE  
    dbo.PARCELS.GDB_ARCHIVE_OID IN 
        (SELECT GDB_ARCHIVE_OID 
         FROM  
             (SELECT 
                  GDB_ARCHIVE_OID,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECTID ORDER BY GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) rn_, 
                  GDB_IS_DELETE 
              FROM 
                  dbo.PARCELS 
              WHERE  
                  ((GDB_BRANCH_ID = 0 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22') 
                   OR (GDB_BRANCH_ID = 1 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22'))) br__ 
         WHERE 
             br__.rn_ = 1 AND br__.GDB_IS_DELETE = 0)  
ORDER BY 
    OBJECTID ASC 
    OFFSET 2000 ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY
```

This is fast without the shape field which is a geometry data type [(paste the plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1LZqL_Pa):

```
SELECT
    OBJECTID
    --,Shape
FROM
    dbo.PARCELS   
WHERE  
    dbo.PARCELS.GDB_ARCHIVE_OID IN  
        (SELECT GDB_ARCHIVE_OID 
         FROM  
             (SELECT 
                  GDB_ARCHIVE_OID,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECTID ORDER BY GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) rn_, 
                  GDB_IS_DELETE 
              FROM 
                  dbo.PARCELS 
              WHERE  
                  ((GDB_BRANCH_ID = 0 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22') 
                   OR (GDB_BRANCH_ID = 1 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22'))) br__ 
         WHERE 
             br__.rn_ = 1 AND br__.GDB_IS_DELETE = 0)  
ORDER BY 
    OBJECTID ASC 
    OFFSET 2000 ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY
```

This is fast without the where clause [(paste the plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJ-nqL_Pa):

```
SELECT
    OBJECTID,
    Shape
FROM
    dbo.PARCELS   
--    WHERE  DBO.PARCELS.GDB_ARCHIVE_OID IN  (
--      SELECT GDB_ARCHIVE_OID 
--      FROM  (
--          SELECT GDB_ARCHIVE_OID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECTID ORDER BY GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) rn_, GDB_IS_DELETE 
--          FROM DBO.PARCELS 
--          WHERE  ((GDB_BRANCH_ID = 0 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22') OR (GDB_BRANCH_ID = 1 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22'))
--          ) br__ 
--      WHERE br__.rn_ = 1 AND br__.GDB_IS_DELETE = 0
--      )  
ORDER BY 
    OBJECTID ASC 
    OFFSET 2000 ROWS 
        FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY
```

This is fast without the paging [(paste the plan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJGCcIdwp):

```
SELECT
    OBJECTID,
    Shape
FROM
    dbo.PARCELS   
WHERE  
    dbo.PARCELS.GDB_ARCHIVE_OID IN  
        (SELECT 
             GDB_ARCHIVE_OID 
         FROM  
             (SELECT 
                  GDB_ARCHIVE_OID,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OBJECTID ORDER BY GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) rn_, 
                  GDB_IS_DELETE 
              FROM 
                  dbo.PARCELS 
              WHERE  
                  ((GDB_BRANCH_ID = 0 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22') 
                   OR (GDB_BRANCH_ID = 1 AND GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22'))) br__ 
         WHERE 
             br__.rn_ = 1 AND br__.GDB_IS_DELETE = 0)  
    ORDER BY 
        OBJECTID ASC 
    -- OFFSET 2000 ROWS 
    -- FETCH NEXT 2000 ROWS ONLY
```

It's the combination of all three, the geometry column, paging and the where clause that kills the query. Without any one of those the execution time is under a second. With all three the execution time is 41 seconds.

Below is the table definition with indexes at the end:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS](
    [OBJECTID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TXID_NMBR] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [TAX_MAP] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [CONTROL] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [PARCEL] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [TIE_BACK] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [LAST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FIRST_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FULL_NAME] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OWNER_ADD] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OWNER_ADD2] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OWNER_CITY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OWNER_ST] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [OWNER_ZIP] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MUNIC] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [SITUS] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [SITUS_CITY] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SITUS_ST] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [SITUS_ZIP] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [USE_] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [NBHD] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [STORIES] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [STYLE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [EXTERIOR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [YR_BUILT] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [GRADE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [BEDROOMS] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [BATHS] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [HALF_BATHS] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [BSMT] [int] NULL,
    [FIN_BSMT] [int] NULL,
    [HEAT] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CENT_AIR] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FIREPLACE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [TERRAIN] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [SEWER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WATER] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [LIV_AREA] [int] NULL,
    [GRANTOR] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DEED] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SALE_DATE] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [SALE_AMT] [int] NULL,
    [VAL_2_SALE] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [PP_ACRE] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [PP_AC_ADJ] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [PP_SQFT] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [PP_SF_ADJ] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [C_AND_G] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [DEED_ACRES] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [LAND_VAL] [int] NULL,
    [BLDG_VAL] [int] NULL,
    [OUT_VAL] [int] NULL,
    [PROP_VAL] [int] NULL,
    [LycoOnline] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [TYPE] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [MUNI_NAME] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [MUNI_TYPE] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [created_user] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [created_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [last_edited_user] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [last_edited_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [SALE_TYPE] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [VALID_SALE] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NULL,
    [Calc_Acres] [numeric](38, 8) NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](150) NULL,
    [GlobalID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [GDB_GEOMATTR_DATA] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [GDB_ARCHIVE_OID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GDB_FROM_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [GDB_IS_DELETE] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [GDB_BRANCH_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GDB_DELETED_AT] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [GDB_DELETED_BY] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [R831_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GDB_ARCHIVE_OID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 95, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = DISABLE)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] ADD  DEFAULT ('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}') FOR [GlobalID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [GDB_FROM_DATE831_def]  DEFAULT (CONVERT([datetime2](3),getutcdate())) FOR [GDB_FROM_DATE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [GDB_IS_DELETE831_def]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [GDB_IS_DELETE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [GDB_BRANCH_ID831_def]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [GDB_BRANCH_ID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [g799_ck] CHECK  (([SHAPE].[STSrid]=(2271)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [g799_ck]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [gdb_ct1_831] ON [dbo].[PARCELS]
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC,
    [GDB_FROM_DATE] ASC,
    [GDB_BRANCH_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 75, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [gdb_ct2_831] ON [dbo].[PARCELS]
(
    [GDB_BRANCH_ID] ASC,
    [GDB_FROM_DATE] ASC,
    [GDB_IS_DELETE] ASC,
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 75, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PARCELS] ADD  CONSTRAINT [R831_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GDB_ARCHIVE_OID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 95, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R831_SDE_ROWID_UK] ON [dbo].[PARCELS]
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 75, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [S799_idx] ON [dbo].[PARCELS]
(
    [Shape]
)USING  GEOMETRY_GRID 
WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(2009646.876269, 328920.783953, 2326307.240322, 522100.77817), GRIDS =(LEVEL_1 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_2 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_3 = MEDIUM,LEVEL_4 = MEDIUM), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UUID_831] ON [dbo].[PARCELS]
(
    [GlobalID] ASC,
    [GDB_BRANCH_ID] ASC,
    [GDB_FROM_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: You need to provide (and take a look yourself) the execution plan ( using Paste The Plan)

Comment: Specifically the actual execution plan (not estimated) as this clearly shows where the time is being spent

Comment: [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) if you don't know the link

Comment: And perhaps three separate plans so the fast can be compared with teh slow.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Charlieface, that might point me in a different way to utilize the API I have to work with to avoid the default paging.  I still don't get why the paging is so fast w/o the geometry field though?

Comment: Without paging it reads the whole table from one index (`102,511` rows) filters that down to `51,246` rows and then hash joins onto `102,511` rows from another index and sorts them. It does have a hugely oversized memory grant of 641,120 KB vs 28,400 KB  used and costs that plan as `632.993` units. Most of it from the sort operator cost. With paging it uses a table spool and ends up replaying `215,349,897` rows from it. It costs that plan as `585.236` units

Comment: So plan may be getting out of shape because `Shape` is a CLR type and it drastically over estimates the cost of including this into the columns going into the sort. The sort in the slow plan does not include this column and is costed less

Comment: What is your real question here? Are you asking for an explanation as to why the query optimiser made a bad choice? Or are you asking how to get acceptable performance for your paginated query? And if the second option do you mean by changing the indexing or by rewriting the query?

Comment: So maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/HRdhAQKd hard to know without understanding what the query is supposed to do and without those missing columns.

Comment: Sorry about the missing columns I revised the question to include them. I was in my prod db instead of test. DOH!

Comment: Thank you for the insight & ideas @Charlieface.  You helped me think of a way to work around this issue by making 2 passes of the API I have to work with.  Pass 1 I get the primary key values then pass 2 I do manual paging to select by primary key value.  This let's me avoid the paging by row index that the API invokes.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have a few concerns.  I'm seeing this performance issue crop up when the end user utilizes the REST API through ArcGIS Pro so just trying to understand the boundaries of the performance problem.  I am open to indexes if that would help but I can only mitigate the how the API queries the SQL Server by understanding its workings a little better and what NOT to do.  lol

Comment: If you improve your indexing, use [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997), and proper row-numbering, then you should have pretty good performance https://dbfiddle.uk/c-UawYV4 You want the following index `PARCELS (OBJECTID, GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) INCLUDE (GDB_BRANCH_ID, GDB_IS_DELETE, Shape)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your query could do with a good bit of improvement, as could your indexes.**

Your primary issue here is basically that there are no indexes that can support the whole query. It's made more complex by an unnecessary self-join.

Firstly, the query can be rewritten to remove the self-join, which is unnecessary. You can pull all the columns straight through from the `ROW_NUMBER` query.

Furthermore, **I strongly suggest you consider [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997)**. This means that instead of reading 2000 rows and discarding them, you jump to the exact place in the index that you need.

So the query can be simplified as follows:

```sql
SELECT TOP (2000)
  br.OBJECTID,
  br.Shape
FROM (
    SELECT 
      p.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.OBJECTID ORDER BY p.GDB_FROM_DATE DESC) rn
    FROM 
      dbo.PARCELS p
    WHERE p.GDB_BRANCH_ID BETWEEN 0 AND 1
      AND p.GDB_FROM_DATE <= '2023-12-22'
      AND p.OBJECTID > @previousMaxID    -- remove this line for the first page
) br
WHERE
  br.rn = 1
  AND br.GDB_IS_DELETE = 0
ORDER BY
  OBJECTID ASC;
```

Note the use of the previous Max ID, in order to paginate to the next key. Remove the final `WHERE` clause for the first page.

---

For indexing, Keyset Pagination normally requires a deterministic sort with a supporting index. The `ROW_NUMBER` also does, so it makes sense to use the same one. And given the row-numbering, we don't need to worry about an extra uniqueifier column, because there is guaranteed to be only one row per `OBJECTID`.

I would suggest the following index, which will support all the `WHERE` clauses, as well as the sort requuirements for both the `ROW_NUMBER` and the Keyset Pagination:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [R831_SDE_ROWID_UK] ON dbo.PARCELS
( OBJECTID ASC, GDB_FROM_DATE DESC)
INCLUDE ( GDB_BRANCH_ID, GDB_IS_DELETE, Shape );
```

If `p.GDB_BRANCH_ID BETWEEN 0 AND 1` is drastically reducing the rowcount then it might make sense to use a different index, perhaps similar to above but with a filter on `GDB_BRANCH_ID`.

---

As you can see, the query plan is nice and neat.

[image]

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Lo3ZhvD3)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Charlieface that index made a big difference in the query performance!