# How to use keyset pagination with ordering if the key is a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, keyset-pagination

Given a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------------+----------+
|title          |enabled   |
+---------------+----------+
|Four           |N         |
|Two            |N         |
|Three          |N         |
|One            |Y         |
|Five           |Y         |
|Six            |Y         |
+---------------+----------+
```

Using keyset pagination and sorting by enabled, how would I would I be able use the title as the key?

For example, using

```
select title, enabled
from my_table
where title > 'Three'
order by enabled;
```

returns

```
+---------------+----------+
|title.         |enabled   |
+---------------+----------+
|Two            |N         |
+---------------+----------+
```

but this removes all rows that have a title that is after `Three` alphabetically, but I would like for it to look like the original result and sreturn the last 3 rows instead.

Comment: Even the order of the table is not guaranteed.  When you run it, it showed Four, Two, Three.  The next time you run it, it may be Two, Three, Four.

Answer (score 1):

In [**Keyset Pagination**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997), the `WHERE >` and `ORDER BY` must be in the same columns, otherwise you are not actually paginating properly.

```sql
select
  mt.title,
  mt.enabled
from my_table
where mt.title > 'Three'
order by
  mt.title
limit 100;
```

You *must* have an index on `(title) INCLUDE (enabled)` or similar, otherwise performance will suffer.

Or you can sort by `enabled, title` but then you need a filter on both as well, and an index `(enabled, title)`.

```sql
select
  mt.title,
  mt.enabled
from my_table
where (mt.enabled, mt.title) > (false, 'Three')
order by
  mt.enabled,
  mt.title
limit 100;
```