# Lock selected sql resources using Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, locking

I am trying to write a `SELECT... FOR UPDATE` query using Entity Framework (for a `Postgresql` db). The problem is that using any `IsolationLevel`, the second request will only block after updating the data (step 2 in the picture) and not from the first (getting the response step in the picture). `Chaos` level is not supported (not sure why).

I need the resources to be locked even from the selection, otherwise both requests will take the same resources!

I can't find a solution using EF, but this will work using a SQL function (+migration) which is not the preferred choice!

thanks

```
// Serializable Summary
//     A range lock is placed on the System.Data.DataSet, preventing other users from
//     updating or inserting rows into the dataset until the transaction is complete.

await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(
    System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
    cancellationToken);

try
{
    var query = _dbContext.ValidationRequests
            .Where(vr => vr.State == Statuses.New)
            .OrderBy(vr => vr.Id);

    var response = await PagedList<Model>.GetPagedListAsync(
        query,
        page,
        pageSize,
        cancellationToken
    );

    await UpdateRangeAsync(response.Items, cancellationToken);

    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);

    return response;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync(cancellationToken);

    throw;
}
```

GetPagedListAsync method:

```
public static async Task<PagedList<T>> GetPagedListAsync(
        IQueryable<T> query,
        int page,
        int pageSize,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        int totalCount = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

        var items = await query
            .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

        return new(page, pageSize, items, totalCount);
    }
```

and the update method:

```
private async Task UpdateRangeAsync(List<Model> requests, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    if (!requests.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    requests.ForEach(item => item.State = Statuses.Pending);

    _dbContext.UpdateRange(requests);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Why not use the new `ExecuteUpdateAsync` then it all happens in one statement? What does `UpdateRangeAsync` actually do? Please don't paste images of code or data, only paste text. Side note: if you have a `using` you don't need an explicit `Rollback`.

Comment: the update is just a status change: 
`response.Items.ForEach(item => item.Status = 'Pending');
dbContext.UpdateRange(response.Items);`

then, the response is returned to the client;

Comment: That makes it perfectly suitable for [`ExecuteUpdateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete). Assuming that you're in EF core 7 or higher.

Comment: And what does `GetPagedListAsync` do, how does it query? We need to see the relationship between these two queries.

Comment: the rest of the added code :d `GetPagedListAsync` is just a selection. The idea is that the first request will select 5 items, update their status and return it to the client. And the second request should not receive the same items because their statuses have already been changed by the first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [the new `ExecuteUpdateAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete) feature to do a joined `UPDATE` statement. This means you don't need a transaction as the whole statement is atomic anyway.

Something like this would work, although I'm not entirely clear on your object model.

```cs
var baseQuery = _dbContext.ValidationRequests
    .Where(vr => vr.State == Statuses.New)
    .OrderBy(vr => vr.Id)
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);

await baseQuery.ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
    .SetProperty(item => item.State, Statuses.Pending),
    cancellationToken);
```

Note that there is no `ToList` anywhere, because that would cause client-side evaluation and doesn't work with `ExecuteUpdate`.

Do note that `Skip` `Take` can be highly inefficient even with a supporting index, and you would be better off using [Keyset Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se).

---

If you need the actual rows then you probably want a `RETURNING` or `OUTPUT` clause (depending on your DBMS), in which case a raw SQL query is probably best.

Unfortunately, Postgres does not allow `LIMIT` directly on the target table so you need a self join.

```cs
var results = await _dbContext.ValidationRequests.FromSql($@"
UPDATE ValidationRequests
SET State = 'New'
FROM (
    SELECT vr.*
    FROM ValidationRequests vr
    ORDER BY vr.Id
    LIMIT {pageSize} OFFSET {(page - 1) * pageSize}
    FOR UPDATE
) vr
  ON vr.Id = ValidationRequests.Id
RETURNING *;
").ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

In SQL Server you could update the subquery directly

```cs
var results = await _dbContext.ValidationRequests.FromSql($@"
UPDATE vr
SET State = 'New'
OUTPUT inserted.*
FROM (
    SELECT vr.*
    FROM ValidationRequests vr
    ORDER BY vr.Id
    OFFSET {(page - 1) * pageSize} ROWS
    FETCH NEXT {pageSize} ROWS ONLY
) vr;
").ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `ExecuteUpdateAsync` returns an `int` (number of affected rows). I need these rows...

Comment: OK see new edit

Comment: Heck, We just have a query like this, but in a sql function, which is called using FromSqlRaw. It's basically only needed to move the query from the SQL function directly into the code, since we're trying to use the "code first" approach and it would be better if we didn't have query migrations