How should my index looks like with this query?
I use infinite scroll on my site and I have to return two parameters.
The first is totalCount, the second an array of users.
In users I show only 50 and then again 50 like Limit 50 OFFSET 10 so I cant use COUNT(*) because then I get only the limit count not the total count so I use a subquery. People can also search for last and surname. Now I am confused how my query should be.
here is my query:
SELECT 
u.id,
u.firstname, 
u.lastname, 
c.company, 
et.name as employement_type,
(
 SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users WHERE tenant_id = $3 AND 
 (firstname LIKE '%'||$1||'%' OR lastname LIKE '%'||$1||'%')
)
 AS total 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN employement_types et ON et.id = u.e_types_id 
LEFT JOIN clients c ON u.company = c.id 
WHERE u.tenant_id = $3 
AND (u.firstname LIKE '%'||$1||'%' OR u.lastname LIKE '%'||$1||'%') LIMIT 50 OFFSET $2

How you would set an index based on this query ?
current my index is like that:
CREATE INDEX users_si_gin_index  ON tbl USING gin  (tenant_id, firstname gin_trgm_ops, lastname gin_trgm_ops);

Is this bad or wrong ? I am very thanful for your advice and help.

Ask the database, using explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this SQL statement.

@FrankHeikens hey, thanks how can I check if my index was hit or not when I use explain ?

Yes of course, that's why you need the query plan. On an (almost) empty table, the index will and should not be used.

The wildcard LIKE is not going to be able to use an index whatever you do, especially with an OR. And do you really need the total count because that is going to be very costly.

@Charlieface I have to calculate the total rows with the fetched rows + offset to stop the next fetch. Do you have another solution for this (its for infinite scroll)

The FETCH stops at the end of the table, you don't need the total count for that. Well OFFSET FETCH is also going to be slow, and will get slower and slower the higher the offset. Consider using Keyset Pagination as I outline https://stackoverflow.com/a/70520457/14868997 but you'd need to order by a unique key otherwise it won't work.

The LIKE and OR predicates will prevent indexes being used properly anyway. And OFFSET FETCH gets slower and slower the higher the offset. Getting the total page count is
If you are doing infinite scrolling this is the perfect use case for Keyset Pagination (paging by key, rather than by row number).
Note the following:

You need to order by a unique key. You can use users.id for this. Your existing query is anyway broken because it has no ORDER BY and therefore the row ordering may be different every time.
Don't try to get the total count. It's very costly calculate, and the user doesn't usually need to know it. If you really do need it then do a separate query for it, and do it only once.

So for the first run:
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.firstname, 
  u.lastname, 
  c.company, 
  et.name as employement_type
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN employement_types et ON et.id = u.e_types_id 
LEFT JOIN clients c ON u.company = c.id 
WHERE u.tenant_id = $3
  AND (u.firstname LIKE '%'||$1||'%' OR u.lastname LIKE '%'||$1||'%')
ORDER BY u.id
LIMIT 50

On the subsequent runs, add a WHERE predicate
  AND u.id > $4

and $4 should be the highest ID you got on the previous run.

Thank you very much. my u.id is a UUID. is that a problem on order by u.id?

No why would there be? As long as it has a unique index to support it.

You might like to try ULIDs (and links within) - see also here.
