effective pagination based on price for an ecommerce website
I have an e-commerce website with hundreds of thousands of products in a table called products. One of the columns in the table is for the price of products.
I constantly fetch new records from the table as the users scroll down. However, pagination via limit & offset is quite expensive as you know. I have quite complicated queries but I will simplify the issue with the below query:
select * from products order by price limit 100 offset 300

One option could have been to get the last loaded product's price and use that price in the next query to load the next batch. Something like below:
select * from products where price > 999.99 order by price limit 100 offset 300

The issue however is the database contains many products with the same price. Hence, it is not possible to use the where clause to continue from where I was left off.
I could do (lower the price slightly)
select * from products where price > 999.98 order by price limit 100 offset 300

to make sure that I do not miss a product but then I do not know where I am in the overall order.
What is the best practices for such a scenario? I use mysql.

if you are using the last shown value in a where condition, you should not have an offset, just a limit (to get one page).  also price can presumably tie, you need a completely unambiguous order, e.g. order by price, id, and then do e.g. where (price,id) > (999.99,1234), or when a tied price is split over two pages you may see some duplicate rows and some missed rows instead of each row being shown just once.

do index price (or use it as the last column in a multi-column index, if your full query needs other columns indexed)

https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Consider using Keyset Pagination, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se/70520457#70520457
