MySQL pagination query is very slow
I have this table using InnoDB as engine:
create table if not exists Playlists(
    UserId bigint unsigned not null,
    Title varchar(50) not null,
    IsPublic bool not null,
    primary key (UserId, Title),
    foreign key (UserId) references Users(Id)
    on delete cascade
    on update cascade
);

This table has a huge amount of datasets around >1_000_000 and they're increasing.
I want to select all playlists that have IsPublic = TRUE and paginate that.
But if I use this
select Title from Playlists where IsPublic = true order by Title limit @myLimit offset @myOffset

the query takes longer and longer.
I also tried using an index like so but no significant improvements either
create index index_playlists_ispublic on Playlists(IsPublic);

Is there any way I can optimize this?

LIMIT without ORDER BY is asking for trouble. There's no reason to expect consistent ordering in each query.

OFFSET has linear complexity, it can't be optimized with indexes. So to find the rows starting at offset N, it has to skip over N rows sequentially.

If you create a composite index on (isPublic, orderingColumn, Title) (where orderingColumn is the column you use in ORDER BY, it can do everything with the index, it doesn't have to access the row data. That should help.

Caution:  This has been flagged as a dup of a SQL Server Q&A.  It does have good concepts, but the syntax is not the same as for MariaDB.

"Remember where you left off" instead of using OFFSET:  Pagination

AKA Keyset Pagination, see eg https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70519518/is-there-any-better-option-to-apply-pagination-without-applying-offset-in-sql-se

@Charlieface - Nice article; it concisely points out the problem, then discusses workarounds (in non-MySQL terms).

The problem is that I don't have the possibility to store the last entry. So I can only do it by count

@Jule - How are you keeping track of the count?  If it is via a [Next] button; that could have the "next" id in its URL.

It's not for a web project. It's for a discord bot using pagination. So I don't have that info unfortunetly

@Jule - What is a "discord bot" and what is it using MySQL for?

A discord bot is a discord user that can run commands basically. I want to show a pagination embed and need to get an n amount of entries for every site. The only info I have is the current page index (0-n)
